# Checkbox checks two times in one click

Tags: android

I have a recycler view and an adapter class. Inside one list cell of the view has a check box. According to the checking one button in my view is enabled/ disabled. But what i found is when makes a one check in the box. The button enabling is called two times. And I uses some single selection for some of the checkboxes (checked the condition using a method called enforcedexclusivity() in my adapter class). So for that checkboxes, unchecking is working properly but checking is called 3 times. I am putting my code below. Please tell me the solution.

```
public class FurtherExtrasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FurtherExtrasAdapter.ViewHolder> {


ArrayList<Item> items;
Context context;
int flag = 0;
private CouponCodeActivity mThis;

public FurtherExtrasAdapter(ArrayList<Item> items, CouponCodeActivity mThis, Context context) {
    this.items = items;
    this.mThis = mThis;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_cell_platform_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    ;
    holder.enrolment.setText(items.get(position).getName());
    holder.selectEnrollment.setChecked(items.get(position).isPreselect());
    holder.selectEnrollment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (items.get(position).isPreselect()) {
                items.get(position).setPreselect(false);

            } else {
                EnforcedExclusivity(position);

            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public void EnforcedExclusivity(int index) {

    if (items.get(index).isExclusive()) {
        items.get(index).setPreselect(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            if (i == index) {
                continue;
            }
            items.get(i).setPreselect(false);
        }


    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            if (items.get(i).isExclusive()) {
                items.get(i).setPreselect(false);

            }
            items.get(index).setPreselect(true);


        }


    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView enrolment;
    CheckBox selectEnrollment;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        enrolment = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_entrollment);
        selectEnrollment = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_select_entrollment);
        selectEnrollment.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {

                    mThis.updateButtonState(1);
                } else {

                    mThis.updateButtonState(-1);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}}
```

And my view class contains below codes.

```
  rv_further=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_further);
  rv_further.setLayoutManager(manager);
            rv_further.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rv_further.setHasFixedSize(true);
            rv_further.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            rv_further.setAdapter(adapter);

 public void updateButtonState(double num) {

    checkedBoxs += num;

        if (checkedBoxs > 0) {
            Log.d("---CHECKED",String.valueOf(checkedBoxs));
            btnApply.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            Log.d("---UNCHECKED",String.valueOf(checkedBoxs));
            btnApply.setEnabled(false);
        }
}
```

Comment: you have added two events for selectEnrollment object. one is click listener and another one is setOnCheckedChangeListener(...)..

Comment: what is the deal in it?

Comment: what is need for making two events for check box. there is setOnCheckedChangeListener()enough

Comment: @Ahamed first on click will check for exclusivity and it will update accordingly. And the setOnchecked will look for changing the button state

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to move all listeners to onBind(...) method. On the first line of onBind(...) set all listeners to null, after that lunch setSelected(...) with correct data and after that set listener to your desired listener.